# Entity Framework Sequential Guid vs Integer Primary Key - Performance?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, sharding, horizontal-scaling

Our database base has ben designed using EF-6 Code First Approach. Initially we had our database designed, keeping `sharding architecture` in mind for multi-tenancy.

However with popularity of economical & dedicated database tiers on Azure, this doesn't seem a wise architecture any more, in order to handle horizontal splitting of SQL Server database at application level.

> Since Guid.NewGuid() is known to cause fragmentation in
>   Indexes where as Integer primary keys are not. Microsoft support recommended
>   to use Sequential Guid over Guid.NewGuid().

With that architectural background, I am getting more biased towards stop using Guid as primary key forever.

> Merging and splitting of DB doesn't seem to be a wise option any more
>   for modern Application Architects.

Correct me, if needed, please!

> Is there any advantage of using Sequential Guid over Integer primary
>   key in SQL Server?

Comment: There are plenty of articles all over the place showing how bad GUIDs, even sequential ones, are. Use INT or BIGINT.

Comment: @srutzky: One could argue that the benefits of guid outweigh the performance penalty. You know what I am talking if you ever came to the situation where you had to merge two datasets from different databases or servers into a single one. Ints are nightmare in this scenario. Guids are collision free and you can merge data from different databses/servers into one without running issue of duplicate primary keys, i.e. id 1 from server a and id 1 from server b

Comment: @Tseng One could argue that, but they would be incorrect ;-). GUIDs only have benefit as Alternate Keys (non-clustered indexed column used to look up the INT / BIGINT PK in a table). I know exactly what you are talking about, but I would never sacrifice the day to day operation of a system (the 95% - 99% use case) for the relatively few occasions that one _might_ run into that would be easier with a GUID PK (the 1% - 5% use case).

Comment: @srutzky: It's also useful in DDD, since you don't need to do perform an additional trip to the DB to obtain the primary key. Also see [Primary Keys: IDs versus GUIDs](https://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/) (btw. Jeff is one of the Co-Founders of SO, so they'll knew a thing or two about databases

Comment: @Tseng For any system that has to scale, GUIDs (at least within SQL Server) are a horrible choice. The post you reference contains no true analysis, no testing, so doesn't offer any real insight. And it is an extremely dangerous habit to infer correctness on technical topics based on association. Jeff is an application developer, not a DBA or even database programmer / expert. And co-founding a successful company says little about technical knowledge, and more about good timing, ideas, and partners / relationships. Neither Bill Gates nor Mark Zuckerberg are great programmers.

Comment: A bit late... but [this article](https://exceptionnotfound.net/integers-vs-guids-the-great-primary-key-debate/) by Matthew Jones (newer than the one posted by @Tseng) explains PROS and CONS of each approach in todays applications scenarios.